# Why we need z-coordinate in Montgomery Curve?

Tags: elliptic-curves

In Montgomery Curve $By^2=x^3+Ax^2+x$, B $\neq$ 0, A $\neq$ +2 or -2.
 First case:
If $x_{1}$=$x_{2}$ and $y_{1}$=$y_{2}$$\neq$0: then s=($3(x_{1})^2$+$2Ax_{1}$)/(2B$v_{1}$).
 If $x_{1}$$\neq$$x_{2}$: then s=($y_{1}-y_{2}$)/($x_{1}-x_{2}$).

In both:
 $x_{3}= Bs^2-A-x_{1}-x_{2}$ and $y_{3}=s(x_{1}-x_{3})-v_{1}$ 
 Second case:
 when we work protectively, when can compute with only X and Z coordinates.
 Point addition take as input:
 P=($x_{p}$:$z_{p}$)
Q=($x_{Q}$:$z_{Q}$)
D=($x_{D}$:$z_{D}$)=P-Q 
 $X_{P+Q}=Z_{D}[(X_{P}-z_{P})(X_{Q}+z_{Q})+(X_{P}+z_{P})(X_{Q}-z_{Q})]^2$ 
 $Z_{P+Q}=X_{D}[(X_{P}-z_{P})(X_{Q}+z_{Q})-(X_{P}+z_{P})(X_{Q}-z_{Q})]^2$ 
 Point doubling take as input:P=($x_{p}$:$z_{p}$)
4$X_{P}$$Z_{P}$=$(X_{P}+Z_{P})^2$ -  $(X_{P}-Z_{P})^2$
 $X_{2P}=(X_{P}+z_{P})^2(X_{P}-z_{P})^2$
$Z_{2P}$=(4$X_{P}$$Z_{P}$)$(X_{P}-z_{P})^2$+$((A+2/4)(4X_{P}Z_{P})$
I can understand why we can eliminate the Y-coordinate from the Montgomery Curve calculations, But I can't understand what is the difference between these two cases?, why we need Z-coordinate ? and what is the meaning of (when we work protectively)?

Comment: @fgrieu, I hope that you can help me in this.

Comment: You added the 'montgomery-multiplication' tag; this is actually about computing on montgomery elliptic curves using the montgomery ladder, neither of which has anything to do with montgomery multiplication (except they were all found by the same guy).  Yeah, life would be less confusing if Mr. Montgomery wasn't so gifted, and so two of those things would have been found by (and named after) someone else...

Comment: @NawrasHussein: FYI, the "at name" thing works in questions or chatrooms only when the named person already participates. I was caught on that one too, the first time.

Comment: FYI, Montgomery already explain in [their initial paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1987-48-177/S0025-5718-1987-0866113-7/S0025-5718-1987-0866113-7.pdf) page 261

Comment: @kelalaka, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not fgrieu, but I'll answer anyways:

> why we need Z-coordinate ?

Actually, we don't need a Z-coordinate; we could rewrite the above equations to use only an X-coordinate.

However, in that case, performing either operation would involve a modular inversion (given $a, p$, find $b$ such that $ab \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$, this is often written as $b = a^{-1}$ (with the $p$ implied)).  That can be done with moderate efficiency, however that "moderate efficiency" is still quite a bit more expensive than modular addition or multiplication.

Including the $z$ coordinate is a considerable speed-up, and so that's what we choose to do.  We'll still need a modular inversion (to convert our $x, z$ format into an $x$-only format that the larger system expects, for example as our ECDH shared secret), however doing it only once is better than doing it several hundred times during our point multiplication operation.

Comment: ,Thanks for your answering. So you mean that if I use the mathematical laws exist in the first case or the second case (in my question) I will get the same result, but we use z coordinate to get better speed in implementing it. Right? Also I hope that you that you explain for me simply what do you mean by (We'll still need a modular inversion (to convert our x,z format into an x-only format that the larger system expects, for example as our ECDH shared secret), however doing it only once is better than doing it several hundred times during our point multiplication operation)

Comment: @NawrasHussein: what is unclear about my statement?  It covers several things (all of which I thought was obvious).  Do you not understand why we need a modular inversion to convert x,z into x; or is it that the larger system wants the point in the x format (generally), or why doing a single modular exponentiation is better than doing it hundreds of times, or why I said "hundreds of times"?

Comment: The questions that you asked represent an answers about the things that it were not clear for me in your previous answer ... what about my first part of my previous comment (So you mean that if I use the mathematical laws exist in the first case or the second case (in my question) I will get the same result, but we use z coordinate to get better speed in implementing it. Right?), can you answer it please.